# Wordpress pagination not working using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, pagination

Ok I know there are a lot posts on this already but I'm not able to find what is wrong with my code. Because pagination is still not working. The weird thing is the same code and template works fine on another site I'm using them on.

```php
<?php
    $type = get_sub_field('type');
    $amount = get_sub_field('amount');
    $previousLabel = $labels['previous_label'];
    $nextLabel = $labels['next_label'];
?>

<div class="block-review block-review-<?php echo($type)?>">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <?php 
            if($type == 'list') {
                // get list of posts
                $pageQuery = (is_home())? 'page' : 'paged';
                $paged = (get_query_var($pageQuery)) ? get_query_var($pageQuery) : 1;
                $reviews = new WP_Query(
                    array( 
                        'post_type' => 'review', 
                        'posts_per_page' => $amount,
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'meta_key' => 'meta_data_hide_review',
                        'meta_value' => '0'
                    )
                );
                // loop though reviews
                if ($reviews->have_posts()):
                    while($reviews->have_posts()): $reviews->the_post();
                        require('element/review-item.php');
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                    <div style="display:none"><?php var_dump(get_query_var('page') . get_query_var('paged'))?></div>
                    <div class="review-pagination-wrapper">
                        <div class="review-pagination">
                            <?php 
                                echo paginate_links( array(
                                    'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                                    'total'        => $reviews->max_num_pages,
                                    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( $pageQuery ) ),
                                    'format'       => '?' . $pageQuery . '=%#%',
                                    'show_all'     => false,
                                    'type'         => 'plain',
                                    'end_size'     => 2,
                                    'mid_size'     => 1,
                                    'prev_next'    => true,
                                    'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( $previousLabel , 'text-domain' ) ),
                                    'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( $nextLabel , 'text-domain' ) ),
                                    'add_args'     => false,
                                    'add_fragment' => '',
                                ) );
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                else:
                    // no posts
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the first page works fine, and pagination show up but i can't navigate to the next pages. Any help would be very very very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry for posting this question. Someone installed a SEO plugin that redirected every consecutive page the page back to the fist page.